# Autohotkey, How to NOT consume the key being pressed?

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey, I want the key pressed to serve its original purpose, while executing some additional functions.

For example, upon pressing "^a", I'd like the "^a" to function as normal (e.g. Select All), and then `send` another "word".

I tried to repeat the key being pressed, i.e. the following:

```
^a::
send, ^a
send, word
return
```

However, if I send the triggering keys (^a) again, the function will become "recursive" and never end.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$~^a::
```

The ~ will pass the ^a code through when the code is executed, so you don't even need to repeat the send, ^a.

Comment: FYI, $ is redundant in this case as ~ also forces the use of the keyboard hook.

Answer (score 5):

I'm an Autohotkey beginner, but I think you use the "$" sign.

```
$^a::
send, ^a
send, word
return
```

> This is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to
>   send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise
>   cause it to trigger itself.

Hotkeys (Mouse, Joystick and Keyboard Shortcuts) > Introduction and Simple Examples > You can use the following > This is usually only

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm